# Can the iOS app open TikTok user profile?

Tags: ios, swift, social-media

Is there a way to open a TikTok user profile in the TikTok app instead of directing to the browser from our app?
Let's use Twitter example as they allow it:

> twitter://user?screen_name=(username)

Comment: There may or may not be a custom URL scheme associated with any given third-party app. However, if it's not publicly documented, you won't be able to do this (redirect to Safari instead) or will have to reverse-engineer it yourself.

Comment: Just tested basic browser URL and if the app is installed on the phone it moves you straight to the app. "https://www.tiktok.com/@\(username)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was found. If the app is installed on the phone and you try to launch a TikTok profile from

> https://www.tiktok.com/@(username)

it will redirect you to the chosen profile in the app.

Comment: not working for me. it's open TikTok app itself but on the feed screen, not user profile

Comment: How about trying this one where username is a variable. "https://www.tiktok.com/@\ (username)"

Comment: new TikTok syntax: `https://www.tiktok.com/@username`

Comment: and remember to use all small letters for the username or it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the TikTok url for the username

Objective-C

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktokusername"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Swift

```
 UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktokusername")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so had similar issue.
I have a link to a tiktok profile to open the app:

```
let tiktokUrl = "tiktok://@userName"
```

Was opening like that:

```
    let application = UIApplication.shared
        guard let url = URL(string: tiktokUrl) else { return }
        if application.canOpenURL(url) {
            application.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            return
        }
    }
```

It was working for a long time. But we just noticed, that now (not sure on which iOS exactly) it started to open only TikTok app, and not the profile

The fix is:
fix URL. It should be:
From:

```
let tiktokUrl = "tiktok://@userName"
```

To:

```
let appUrl = "https://www.tiktok.com/@userName
```

And opening, just use .open:

From:

```
application.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

To:

```
application.open(url)
```

So 2 things to fix: URL address so it is https://www.tiktok.com/@userName and HOW you open. Do not pass these `options` and `completionHandler`, as with these it will still open only the TikTok app.

By the way, the previous way I used still works for all other social networks: youtube, facebook, Instagram, but I had issues ONLY with tiktok.

Hope that will save someones time in the future